# Finding the zeroes of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, systems-of-equations

> How do I find the zeroes of the function $S$, below?

I want to find the zeroes of $$S = 4\psi_2$$
Where
$$\dot{\psi}_1=2\psi_2$$
$$\dot{\psi}_2=-2\psi_1$$

and I have that(from below) $$\begin{pmatrix}\psi_1 \\ \psi_2\end{pmatrix} = Ae^{2it}\begin{pmatrix}i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}+Be^{-2it}\begin{pmatrix}-i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$
I have two equilibrium points that are centre nodes at $(2,0)$ and $(-2,0)$

So I suppose this is equivalent to finding the zeroes of the function:

$$S = 4(Ae^{2it}+Be^{-2it})$$

And eigenvector: $\underset{\sim}{v}_1=\begin{pmatrix}i \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ for $\lambda=2i$

And eigenvector: $\underset{\sim}{v}_2=\begin{pmatrix}-i \\1\end{pmatrix}$ for $\lambda = -2i$

Answer (score 1):

When you have 
\begin{equation}
\dot{\psi}_1 = 2\psi_2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\dot{\psi}_2 = -2\psi_1,
\end{equation}
you can re-write this as
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c} \dot{\psi}_1 \\ \dot{\psi}_2 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rc} 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} \psi_1 \\ \psi_2 \end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
Call the matrix above $A$. $A$ takes the general form of a matrix $M$ defined as
\begin{equation}
M = \left(\begin{array}{rc} \sigma & \omega \\ - \omega & \sigma \end{array}\right),
\end{equation}
and the exponential for such matrices takes the form
\begin{equation}
\exp(Mt) = e^{\sigma t}\left(\begin{array}{rc} \cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t) \\ - \sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) \end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
Using the values of $\sigma = 0$ and $\omega = 2$ we have in $A$ above, we get
\begin{equation}
\exp(At) = \left(\begin{array}{rc} \cos(2 t) & \sin(2 t) \\ - \sin(2 t) & \cos(2 t) \end{array}\right).
\end{equation}
Then solving for $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ gives
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{c} \psi_1(t) \\ \psi_2(t) \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rc} \cos(2 t) & \sin(2 t) \\ - \sin(2 t) & \cos(2 t) \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} \psi_1(t_0) \\ \psi_2(t_0) \end{array}\right). 
\end{equation}

From this we get that
\begin{equation}
S = -4\sin(2t)\psi_1(t_0) + 4\cos(2t)\psi_2(t_0). 
\end{equation}
You can plug in any initial condition, $\big(\psi_1(t_0), \psi_2(t_0)\big)^T$ of interest and solve for the zeros of $S$ from there.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, I will let it settle in my mind and ask for any clarification

Comment: What if I have no initial conditions? This is for the switching function for optimal control. $\begin{pmatrix}\dot{x}_1 \\ \dot{x}_2\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0&2\\-2&0\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}0\\4u\end{pmatrix}$ where $|u|\leq1$

Comment: @Analysis Is this a minimum time optimal control problem?